# Recaptcha giving 404 error on Validate in SSL site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, recaptcha

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I am using the `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` (from the NuGet package) and my code is a very basic implementation of ReCaptcha. In my view I have:

```
@ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "clean")
```

In my controller I have:

```
Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate();
```

The complexity comes with the SSL implementation we are using.

I have added the appropriate settings to my web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://***proxy script settings**" 
            autoDetect="False" 
            usesystemdefault="False" 
            bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

There seems like there is nothing further I can do in terms of config, but I am getting the error message

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

when I hit the recaptcha validate method on the form post method in my controller.

Ive found a number of other answers on here but they all seem to suggest that you change the url, or upgrade. As Im using a NuGet package I would have thought I was using the latest version. Any ideas or links with more information greatly appreciated. Ive already done quite a bit of looking both on this site and google

**edit:**

I have found that earlier versions of firefox have trouble actually rendering the recapture box given our network conditions, but the latest one is fine. As the validation is done on the controller though, I suppose there is no issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much pulling of hair and general confusion, I discovered that the problem was that the POST (but not the GET) to the google API was being blocked by our corporate firewall. I had previously discounted this, because I could navigate to the service that recaptcha uses (http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify).

I found this by constructing an HTML page of the requisite parts for the post and submitting it in a browser. The corporate "This page is blocked" appeared - however in code the error that is returned is a 404. The error is somewhat misleading, but this is bizarre behavior from our infrastructure department.